# spyOn fail even if the spy was called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

In my component I have ...

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { history, versionStore } = this.props;
  versionStore.add(this.state.formData)
    .then(() => history.push('/'));
}
```

On my test...

```
it('after successfully submit should redirect to / page', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(minProps.history, 'push')
    .mockImplementation((path) => {
      console.log('called with ', path); // IS CALLED!
    });

  const wrapper = shallow(<Add.wrappedComponent {...minProps} />);

  fetchMock.postOnce('/api/version', { name: 'v1' });
  wrapper.setState({ formData: { name: 'v1' } });

  wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: jest.fn() });

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/');

  spy.mockReset();
  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

The test fail with

> called with  /
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)
>
> Expected mock function to have been called with: ["/"]
> But it was not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your redirect is inside of asynchronous code and you are testing it in a synchronous manner, meaning when the test executes the promise is not resolved yet. I would tackle this in one of 2 ways

1 - test your submit function w/o the event, then you can return the promise and test the redirection after the promise chain is successful

2 - mock versionStore.add to be synchronous and immidattly execute it's then function.